# How to prove a regular pentagon is formed by knotting a rectangular strip of paper?

Tags: geometry, galois-theory, euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics, knot-theory

I found this interesting problem from a friend (From Arthur Engel's-*Problem Solving Strategies* book).

The method to begin the problem is as follows-

> Step 1.Take a rectangular strip of paper
>
> Step 2.We all know how to make a knot.Do the same (make a knot) using the strip of paper and fold it along the creases to form a polygon.
>
> (If you are having a problem to make the knot please go to this link to see how to do it. See [here](https://youtu.be/q1zAwHIXoYI) )
>
> Step 3.Prove that the polygon $abcde$ formed is regular.

[image]

What I could make out from the thing-

When I open the fold again I get this-

[image]

Note:-**e** is mentioned by dotted lines with pencil since **e** lies in the opposite side of the paper.

Now,my intuition somehow suggest that $a$ and $b$ must be mutually parallel and $d$ and $e$ must also be parallel.(Since then they would become congruent trapeziums).

But unfortunately I have no clue on how to prove this or how to prove that they are equal to $c$.

Any help or response is highly appreciated and thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: A link showing how to make a knot would be very useful!   (PS: I don't know)

Comment: @N.S.JOHN Follow this link to learn how to make it-https://youtu.be/q1zAwHIXoYI

Comment: Thanks. It is better to tell it in the question.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN Its very difficult to describe the process in words.You may please do it if you are able to...Thanks!!

Comment: Here's a purely geometrical formulation of the problem: Let the vertices of the pentagon be labeled $PQRST$ (with $P$ being the one where edges $a$ and $e$ meet). Because $QT$ and $RS$ are opposite sides of a rectangular paper strip, they are parallel and a unit distance apart. The same is true for the pairs of line segments $PQ$ and $RT$, $QS$ and $TP$, and $QR$ and $PS$. Given this information we have to prove that the pentagon $PQRST$ is regular.

Comment: Your question is properly answered at [Regular pentagon folding a strip](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4420109/regular-pentagon-folding-a-strip).

Comment: @user21820  I think it is clear that the target you link to is actually a dupe of this, and I have so voted.

Comment: Please, instead of user21820's suggestion to close this as a dupe of a question asked only two years ago, that users supporting this post instead, close [this recent post, answered by user21820](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4420109/regular-pentagon-folding-a-strip), as a duplicate of this better question and answer.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if it's a complete answer, but an attempt to check a converse statement...

Consider the following illustration:
[image: paper strip]

The quadrilateral $ABCD$ is a rhombus (the other $D$ on the right is the length of the diagonal, sorry for the confusion between letters)
We have that
\begin{equation}
d=\frac{1}{\sin\theta},\qquad D=\frac{1}{\cos\theta}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
a = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{D^2+d^2},\qquad b = a-2d\cos\theta
\end{equation}
Let's suppose that we want a regular polygon. Then we have to impose that the segments $DE$ and $EB$ are of equal length. Since $\overline{DE}=d$ and $\overline{EB}=b$, that means imposing $d=b$:
\begin{equation}
d=b\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{\sin\theta}\left(\frac{1}{2\cos\theta}-\frac{2}{\tan\theta}-1\right)=0
\end{equation}
i.e.
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{1}{2\cos\theta}-\frac{2}{\tan\theta}-1\right)=0
\end{equation}
The only solution to this equation in the interval $[0,\pi/2]$ is actually  $\theta=2\pi/5$.

Comment: I cannot make out why ABCD is a rhombus....

Comment: Because the red line AB is the fold: CD is perpendicular to the fold and is cut in half by the fold itself.

Comment: You have drawn two $D$ s...What does the $D$ between $AC(=a)$ actually signify?What is that point actually?

Comment: that $D$ is the length of the longest diagonal of the rhombus.