# Prove that the equivalence of 2 knots is an equivalence relation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, equivalence-relations, knot-theory, knot-invariants

The definition of equivalence of 2 knots according to Richard H. Crowell and Ralph H. Fox, edition 1963, is:

Assume that $K_{1}$,$K_{2}$ are 2 knots in $\mathbb{R^3}$, then they are equivalent , denoted by $K_{1} \cong K_{2}$, iff $\exists f: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$, where $f$ is a homeomorphism and such that $f(K_{1}) = K_{2}.$

**My Thoughts:**

I know that to prove that a relation is an equivalence relation, I have to prove that it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

Also, I know that $f$ is a homeomorphism iff $f$ is bijective and continuous and $f^{-1}$ is continuous. and that this leads to $\mathbb{R^3}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^3}$, which is trivially true, so what is the benefit of the $f$ function?

Now, for proving that the given relation is reflexive I will take $f =$ identity function , which is a homeomorphism and $f(K_{1}) = K_{1}.$

For proving that it is symmetric,I know the definition which is: if $K_{1} \cong K_{2}$ then $K_{2} \cong K_{1}$, but I do not know how to prove this, could anyone help me in this please?

For proving that it is transitive: I know the definition which is: if $K_{1} \cong K_{2}$ and if $K_{2} \cong K_{3}$ then $K_{1} \cong K_{3}$, and I know that this requires me to prove that if $f(K_{1}) = K_{2}$ and $f(K_{2}) = K_{3}$, then $f(K_{1}) = K_{3}$, but I do not know how to conclude this, could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition says that two knots are equivalent if there exists a homeomorphism $f \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, such that the restriction of $f$ yields a homeomorphism between the knots. The benefit is exactly that. We have a homeomorphism between the knots which can be lifted to/comes from the entire space where the knots live.

Assume that $K_1 \cong K_2$. This means that we have a homeomorphism $f \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, such that $f(K_1) = K_2$. We now need to find a homeomorphism $g \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, such that $g(K_2) = K_1$. How about $g = f^{-1}$?

For the transitivity just compose the maps that you are assuming to have. By assumption we have $f \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, such that $f(K_1) = K_2$ and $g \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, such that $g(K_2) = K_3$. This means we can just consider $g \circ f$ which is a homeomorphism then and by the definition of $f$ and $g$ we have $g(f(K_1)) = K_3$. That means that $K_1$ and $K_3$ are equivalent.

Comment: I think in the second paragraph you mean that $g(K_{2}) = g(K_{1})$ ..... correct?

Comment: Yes. Was typing too fast.

Comment: And we have to be sure that the composition is homeomorphism ..... orrect?

Comment: Yes, but that is clear since both maps are homeomorphisms.

Comment: Could you please look at this question (when you have time)? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3275381/show-that-there-are-no-knotted-quadrilaterals-or-pentagons-what-knot-types-are

Answer (score 1):

If $K_1\simeq K_2$, then there's a homeomorphism $f$ of $\Bbb R^3$ taking $K_1$ to $K_2$. Then consider $f^{-1}$ for $K_2\simeq K_1$.

For transitivity, we have an $f$ taking $K_1$ to $K_2$ and *perhaps another* $g$ taking $K_2$ to $K_3$. Just compose them.

Comment: Could you please look at this question (when you have time)? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3275381/show-that-there-are-no-knotted-quadrilaterals-or-pentagons-what-knot-types-are